# Capture screen on Xamarin.android get black screen - using Libvlc

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, libvlc, screen-capture, libvlcsharp

I am using LibVLCSharp to play video , and trying to capture the screen.
I am getting black screen , like the surface-view cant be captured.
tried many different capture methods , non of them works.
api 23 android 6.

Any one have a solution/example please?

Comment: This sounds like you app might have the SecureFlag enabled to prevent you from capture screenshots. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE double check that this isn't set

Comment: libvlc has its own snapshot feature. Would it be enough for your use case?

Comment: it didnt work for me so i gave up , but now its working (see my post). thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i managed to figure it out,
i managed to use the libvlc takesnapshot method.
Apparently it didn't work because of a bad filename i gave, so the image wasn't saved.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer ,which will help more people .